# В чем разница между Helpers и Partials в handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите пожалуйста. Смотрю доки по *handlebars* и не совсем понимаю в чем принципиальная разница между *[Helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html)* и *[Partials](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html)* .
*Helpers* , если я правильно понял - это функция коллбэк, которая отображает результат выполнения в шаблоне.
Так *Partials* делает же то же самое, подскажи те, в чем принципиальная разница у них?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helpers - небольшие функции помошники
Partials - реюзабельные части шаблона.

Helpers служат для каких-либо вспомогательных функций.
Partials полноценные шаблоны, которые используются(могут использоваться) в других шаблонах.